# Matlab. How to make a vector into the header of a matrix and so turning it into a table or data set

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

In matlab as part of another set of code. I am trying to make a table or a data set with a matrix as the data and a vector of numbers as the headers. First element of the vector being the header of the first column and so on. Here is some example code for the matrix and vector.

```
p_vec = 0:0.5:1;
M = rand(10,length(p_vec));
```

After some messing around I can get:

```
header = 100*p_vec;
header = arrayfun(@num2str, header, 'UniformOutput', false)
Table = mat2dataset(M,'VarNames',header);
```

To produce a table with the almost correct headers. Except there is an x before each number in the header. Could I get rid of them or replace them with  % sign afterwards. The x's are probably there to make sure Matlab does not confuse a string with a number, when making tables.

Comment: please be more clear about what you wish to achieve.. maybe provide an example of the end result. thanks

Comment: A table column name cannot contain a dot, so you can't use `0.5` as a column header. see http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html#namevaluepairs

Comment: The lowest value I am working with with in p_vec within the code I am using is 0.05. It represents a proportion so multiply by 100 and getting this as percentage and then using the percentage vector, as the header would get around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I've interpreted what you want correctly, you have a matrix of numbers:

```
m = [1 2 3 4 5;
     6 7 8 9 0;
     1 2 3 4 5;
     6 7 8 9 0];
```

And you have a vector of numeric column names:

```
names = [10 20 30 40 50];
```

And you want to end up with something like this:

```
f = [10 20 30 40 50
     1  2  3  4  5;
     6  7  8  9  0;
     1  2  3  4  5;
     6  7  8  9  0];
```

Then you'd want something like this:

```
f = [names; m];
```

Edit: If you want something more akin to R's ability to name columns in your matrices, letting you use the names to access parts of the matrix, I don't know if matlab has this functionality.

Comment: That concatenates a column vector to the top of a matrix. You can set a headers for tables before saving them as a csv files.

Comment: Sorry I wrote this answer before seeing your edit. I don't have any experience doing what you want though, and I'm not sure why you're getting those x's.

Answer (score 1):

In MATLAB a table header is a variable. MATLAB doesn't support variable to start with anything other than a letter.

> "A valid variable name is a character string of letters, digits, and underscores, totaling not more than namelengthmax characters and beginning with a letter." - [doc isvarname](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isvarname.html)

incidentally calling namelengthmax in the command window shows the max length of an identifier is 63